# Dependencies of Apache HttpComponents for async and non-async requests

Tags: java, maven, apache-httpcomponents

In my application I'm using Apache HttpClient for synchronous requests. My maven dependency looks like this:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

But now I need ability to make asynchronous requests.

My general question is - how should look my `pom.xml` if I want to make async and non-async requests using Apache Http Components? Actually there a lot of questions making me a bit confused.

To be more specific:

- is async client is separate dependency? From my understanding - yes, but after adding this dependency to my `pom.xml`:

  ```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
          <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
          <version>4.1.2</version>
      </dependency>
  ```

  I have problems with importing `HttpAsyncClients` class.
- Does this both libs use same http-core dependency? May be I should use exclusion for  `http-core`?
- Is there any other way to have async and non-async requests with Apache HttpComponents?
- Is it legal to mix both libraries in one project?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest keeping just `httpasyncclient`, you can always process requests synchronously with it. So, if it's possible, just refactor you code to `httpasyncclient`. If not, you can try adding manual dependency on `http-core-nio`, which might solve your problem.